# insert/read html file from blob field

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

How can I INSERT and RETRIEVE with SQL language, an HTML document from a BLOB field into db2 on ibmI ??

I put the testing.html inside fylesystem but I don't know if this way is correct or if I can also use a file into my local PC.

I tried this code from STRSQL without success:

```
INSERT INTO LIB/FILE VALUES('','C','000001',BLOBFROMFILE(/PATH/testing.html))
```

Is it possible to enter an HTML document type or is there another type field to manage it?

After this procedure I need also a SQL string than can read it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = file_get_contents("/PATH/testing.html");
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
$query = "INSERT INTO FILE VALUES('','C','000001','$data')";
mysql_query($query);
```

edit:

## linux file system

**lets assume you are working on `/var/www/username/public_html/` folder**

when u try `/PATH/testing.html`

program looking for `/PATH/testing.html`

direct access to root folder probably u dont have that right

in the other hand when you try `PATH/testing.html` `( no / at start )`

program look for `/var/www/username/public_html/PATH/testing.html`

Comment: i'm not sure will it work, dont have a testing platform at the moment. Can you try and let me know please.

Comment: i try it, but not work! no error show but nothing happens into file, i'm using zendFramework on ibmI

Comment: it wasn't sending query to server,i thinked u will handle rest anyway i added other parts

Comment: yeah a try it! strange is that if i do: $data = file_get_contents("/PATH/testing.html"); print_r($data); nothing happen

Comment: thanks! i try this... if i use a jpg file in the same path, i see result on file_get_contents, while if i try with html document, no results!